# Datatable getting tuple as an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, datatable

so i ran into an problem with an Unity project i am currently on making

I have an Datatable with stats for different parts[Weight,Products,...] in a script
in this database there are multiple Tuples that i created. For example my Thrust `Tuple<string, int>` in the database( in the sixth row) this tuple is assigned with this:

```
Tuple.Create("WASD",1)
```

WASD are the Directions the Thruster can fire and 1 is the strength.

at one part in my code I wanted to add the second value(1) to a variable.
however it is just not working.
if I print the Tuple out i get:

> (WASD, 1)
>
> UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object)
> Master:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/Master.cs:68)

witch is fine

but I can not access it. it says it is an object but if I do `GetType()` I get:

> System.Tuple`2[System.String,System.Single]

I can't access it with `Item2` or `Item1`.
it's just (WASD,1)

```
BStats.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Block", typeof(string)));
BStats.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("live", typeof(float)));
BStats.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Weight", typeof(float)));
BStats.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Products", typeof(Tuple<string,float>)));
BStats.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Thrust", typeof(Tuple<string,float>)));
BStats.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Consume", typeof(Tuple<string, float>)));
BStats.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Desc", typeof(string)));

BStats.Rows.Add("Energy",1F,3F,Tuple.Create("Energy",1.0F),Tuple.Create("NAN",0F),
Tuple.Create("Thori  um", 0.1F), "a Thorium Reactor");

BStats.Rows.Add("Armor", 5F, 4F, Tuple.Create("NAN", 0F), Tuple.Create("NAN", 0F),
Tuple.Create("NAN", 0F), "a simple Armor block");

BStats.Rows.Add("Engine", 2F, 2F, Tuple.Create("NAN", 0F), Tuple.Create("WASD", 1F),
Tuple.Create("Fuel", 0.2F), "a space engine");

BStats.Rows.Add("Gun", 1.5F, 0.5F, Tuple.Create("NAN", 0F), Tuple.Create("NAN", 0F),
Tuple.Create("Energy", 0.5F), "a simple laser Gun");

BStats.Rows.Add("Command Capsule", 3F, 5F, Tuple.Create("NAN", 0F), Tuple.Create("NAN", 0F),
Tuple.Create("Energy", 0.1F), "the Heart of your spaceship.");

print(BStats.Rows[2][4])
```

I am new to Unity so it's gonna be a stupid mistake or the way i use Datatables is just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataRow`'s indexer has [return type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.item?view=netcore-3.1#System_Data_DataRow_Item_System_Int32_) of `object` so you need to [cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#explicit-conversions) it to `Tuple<string,float>`:

```
var tuple = (Tuple<string,float>)BStats.Rows[2][4];
Cosole.WriteLine(tuple.Item1)
```